# Microsoft Unity Service is null when controller is hit

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

I'm looking at Microsoft Unity injection for a webapi we've based on the full stack code i found here;

[Full Stack WebApi GitHub Repo](https://github.com/carbonrobot/FullStackEF)

Now when I run the code and hit the patients controller in this case, the

```
[Dependency]
public PatientService PatientService { get; set; }
```

is null.

Now the patient service is the entity having the context injected into its constructor.

```
public class PatientService : BaseService
{
    private readonly Func<IUCareDataContext> _contextFactory;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="PatientService"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="contextFactory">The context factory.</param>
    public PatientService(Func<IUCareDataContext> contextFactory)
    {
        this._contextFactory = contextFactory;
    }
```

From looking at the Unity documentation and UnityConfig.cs I can see that the Register is completed, but no Resolve?

```
namespace CCS.Services.WebApi
{
   using CCS.Data.UCare;
   using Data;
   using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
   using System.Web.Http;
   using Unity.WebApi;

public static class UnityConfig
{
    public static void RegisterComponents()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<IUCareDataContext, UCareDataContext>();

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
    }
}
}
```

[Unity [Dependency] Attribute MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649447.aspx)

Is this implementation missing something or should the dependency injection just work automatically when the controller is instantiated?

As it was pointed out I could inject the service. But this would then mean I would have to register every service to unity, with all services ultimately having the same context interface being injected to it. I would have thought there is a way around this?

Comment: Can you show us your `UnityConfig.cs` file?

Comment: It's essentially the same as the one in the repo.

Comment: I added the unity config.cs for reference :)

Comment: You need to register `PatientService `

Comment: I edited the question. The patient service is the one having the context injected into it? It's looks like it should work apart from the fact there isn't a .resolve anywhere.

Comment: @MatthewFlynn, Have you tried using the `PatientsService` with constructor injection into the `PatientsController` ie `PatientsController(PatientsService service)`

Comment: @Nkosi I could. But I would then need to create a register for ever service then. For example if I added a doctor or hospital service. As all the services would ultimately have the same context injected I thought that there may be a way around having to do this.